# Calculate percentage change between two columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe df having revenue of 3 months by user, and need to find percent change between august and july using python,

```
user  revenuejune  revenuejuly  revenueaugust

Sam      231.13      1345.2        2455
```

Output

```
 user  revenuejune  revenuejuly  revenueaugust    change
    
    Sam      231.13      1345.2        2455.       82.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['change'] = ((df['revenueaugust'] - df['revenuejuly'])/df['revenuejuly']*100)
```

Output:

```
  user  revenuejune  revenuejuly  revenueaugust     change
0  Sam       231.13       1345.2           2455  82.500743
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood it right. But I guess you just need to add a new column based on a operation between coluns `revenueaugust` and `revenuejuly`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': ['Sam', 'Bob'],
        'revenuejune': [231.13, 200],
        'revenuejuly': [1345.2, 300],
        'revenueaugust': [2455, 400],
    }
)

data['change'] = (data['revenueaugust'] - data['revenuejuly'])/ data['revenuejuly'] * 100

print(data)
```

Output:

```
  name  revenuejune  revenuejuly  revenueaugust     change
0  Sam       231.13       1345.2           2455  82.500743
1  Bob       200.00        300.0            400  33.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for calculating the difference between august and july.

```
df["change"] = (df["revenueaugust."] - df["revenuejuly"]) / df["revenuejuly"] * 100
```